# Typescript: How to type rest object destructure

Tags: typescript, destructuring

If I have these two objects

```
interface Input {
    one?: string;
    two?: string;
    c?: string
}

interface Data {
    one?: string;
    a?: string;
    b?: string;
    c?: string
}
```

currently I have to do something like

```
const { one, two, ...restOfData } = input;
const data: Data = {...restOfData};
```

Is it possible to type `...restOfData` directly?

I would like to be able to do this

```
const { one, two, ...data } = input;
data.one = 'test' + one;
data.a = one;
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can type the destructure as intersection of `Input` and a type which has all fields from `Data` but optional. For that "optional Data" type, you can use built-in [`Partial`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-1.html#mapped-types) type:

```
const { one, two, ...data }: Input & Partial<Data> = input; 
// data type is  inferred as data: { c: string; a?: string; b?: string; }
// so you now can
data.a = one;
```

If you want some properties to remain in the `data` object, I can't think of anything better than doing two destructuring, one without "rest" object, and the second one with it. If you want `one` to remain in `data`, but remove `two`, you can do this

```
interface Input {
    one?: string;
    two?: string;
    c?: string
}

interface Data {
    one?: string;
    a?: string;
    b?: string;
    c?: string
}
let input: Input;

const { one } = input;
const { two, ...data }: Input & Data = input;

data.one = 'test' + one;
data.a = one;
```

If you want all properties to remain, you can have `data` as shallow copy of `input` like this

```
const { one, two } = input;
const { ...data }: Input & Data = input;
```

Comment: Why is `Partial<T>` necessary here, given all `Data` fields are optional already?

Comment: @zerkms sorry in the process of updating the question to be more accurate.

Comment: That works pretty well but doesn't seem like it when I have to fields that are shared between the two objects. Will do some more digging to see if I can find a way around this

Comment: Ah it is because `one` is removed by the destructure therefore `...data` will not have a `one` field. Not sure how to get around this.

Comment: No idea how to do it in only one destructuring, but it can be done easily with two. I updated the answer.

Comment: Hmm input will still have the `two` field in that case but `two` isn't available on `Data`. Will mark this as correct though as I don't think there is a better way at the moment. Thanks!