# How to alter multiple functions of an object at once?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have an object that looks like this:

```js
export declare interface Logger {
  info(msg: string, options?: LogOptions): void;
  warn(msg: string, options?: LogOptions): void;
  warnOnce(msg: string, options?: LogOptions): void;
  error(msg: string, options?: LogOptions): void;
  clearScreen(type: LogType): void;
  hasErrorLogged(error: Error | RollupError): boolean;
  hasWarned: boolean;
}
```

I want to create a new object that has all the same properties but with altered `info`, `warn`, `warnOnce` and `error` functions. The changes to each function are the same.

I tried the following but TypeScript says `Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string | number | symbol' can't be used to index type`:

```js
const alterMsg = (msg: string) => msg.replaceAll('A', 'B');
const alterOptions = {
  flag: false,
};

const logger: Logger = createLogger();
const { clearScreen, hasErrorLogged, hasWarned, ...functionsToAlter } = logger;

Object.keys(functionsToAlter).forEach(key => {
  const originalFunction = functionsToAlter[key as keyof Partial<Logger>];
  const alteredFunction = (msg: string, options?: LogOptions) =>
    originalFunction(alterMsg(msg), {
      ...alterOptions,
      ...options,
    });
  functionsToAlter[key as keyof Partial<Logger>] = alteredFunction;
});

const newLogger: Logger = {
  ...functionsToChange,
  ...logger,
};
```

The type should stay the same. It is still the same object structure and each of the functions still accepts a string `msg` and an optional `options` object.

Comment: Oh so the types appear the same but the impl is different. Ok.

Comment: "*but TypeScript says no*" - what error are you getting?

Comment: The problem here is really the fact that `functionsToAlter` has a `{}` type. For some reason TypeScript can't infer the correct type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kind of partial solution:

Based on this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/50593801/5089567 typing destructuration helps infer `functionsToChange`'s type

```
const { clearScreen, hasErrorLogged, hasWarned, ...functionsToChange }: Logger & Partial<Logger> = logger;
```

Then instead of

```
key as keyof Partial<Logger>
```

use

```
key as keyof Omit<Logger, 'clearScreen' | 'hasErrorLogged' | 'hasWarned'>
```

And finally

```
const newLogger: Logger = {
  clearScreen, hasErrorLogged, hasWarned,
  ...functionsToChange,
};
```

Works fine in [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=11&ssc=22&pln=10&pc=41#code/C4TwDgpgBAMg9gcwPJmASzgOwM5QLxQDeAvgLABQoksiAKuNAQOQCGTUAPlEwEZMUUAJhADGAGxYAnaGkzAIkgGYsR0eAgQKiFKFFmK4ACgC22BAC4o2YJNkIANFDioMOAPyX1KdFmwBKSwA3ODRBAG4dKAB3KUwTM0trW0wHJxdfDxpkdJwAqGDQiPJdGMlMJExVeIsrGztHZx93T0RvV38gkPDIhUk4SWrEupSGnOxMrzG8gu7iqHEIKQBlEWkIOKoIFoR6SGmuot0ACxZsAFFJPsl1TUFDXv7LC6u8njg4MUXMQ6gT7AB1WIQQSWN4fL5FMjkCjiU64G5aQiRfRGUw1JL1NJNcbbNq+PxEYg-UpxNFDZKpRrtCatKaE4mxCpVMm1CmjbE07LYgkkH4PAYsjEjLHU3F03mRBbLVYQdaGTbbXYQHlEyJ-Z79BF3flPS79HlQaTAACuZSgyjE2Agqrmf0BZWB+HNLEtEEhAnIIl8wCgLvkkgAsmYnYNWXYCXgAHxQNEAOmkYAkVSYAEEmI4mAAhJh+IpenA+v0KPE4J1IuaKCQ1C1W+wUG0w71QMSITSSbZtp2YCBRLJtwy5j356xEeafaVrTCOdV666t4HT0727uCRyx9eKY2VbG0OAAYROKWgxA7WgAZFAAApSdAugA8CMk0YILY0CiKFCQPAAVqJgLGAGsIBAbBDE3bd2l3A8WCPPxYwMSQzhUI5DCAkB8GjctdGHH1+jQBBZBdAAxLcRCaJ1wLIyD90PTQAG00N9XA0LgRQoCQYw0GAB950kDMpUkFZJ3YLgmBnK4tRE7g7SBQQmEjABdH4cN9MR-WBEiIKwENBWGSkxk5Et-AwyJdDwgjMGI0imkMItAzMao-EcLDdFc9dYzsoy6zmVyoHcqlfG83ziEHCtrOo6CjwY4CmKgFi2I4rieLfPjuAEoTZUwKSxNODU5zfOTOGkpdZPkhSnTsjTwqwSFQsbAsoG7KJH1PSQy1MsdFkEmV1kXc5Zy1PrlwXSJ3MoncaJgzRvKJIA)